# How to resolve "Null check operator used on a null value"

Tags: flutter, dart

I have migrated my existing project to Dart 3.0.5 . First it gave the error of null safety, somehow i resolved it by applying '?' and '!' wherever it was necessary. The app run without throwing any error. Now it is giving run time error "Null check operator used on a null value" whenever i save any data in SQLite.

I have tried giving '??' but it is throwing error

```
Future _onSubmit() async {
try {
  int _result = 0;
  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
    if (_isSupplier == false && _isCustomer == false) {
      showToast(global.appLocaleValues!['vel_select_ac_type']);
    } else {
      // showLoader(global.appLocaleValues!['txt_wait']);
      setState(() {});
      if (_isCustomer == true && _isSupplier == false) {
        _accountType = 'Customer';
      } else if (_isCustomer == false && _isSupplier == true) {
        _accountType = 'Supplier';
      } else if (_isCustomer == true && _isSupplier == true) {
        _accountType = ',Customer,Supplier,';
      }
      account!.accountType = _accountType!;
      account!.firstName = _cFirstName.text.trim();
      account!.lastName = _cLastName.text.trim();
      account!.middleName = _cMiddleName.text.trim();
      account!.mobile = _cMobile.text.trim();

      //    account!.mobileCountryCode = _cMobileCountryCode.text.trim();
      //    account!.phoneCountryCode = _cPhoneCountryCode.text.trim();
      account!.phone = _cPhone.text.trim();
      account!.email = _cEmail.text.trim();
      if (_birthDate != null) {
        account!.birthdate = DateTime.parse(_birthDate!);
      }
      if (_anniversary != null) {
        account!.anniversary = DateTime.parse(_anniversary!);
      }
      account!.gender = _gender!;
      account!.imagePath = _photopath!;
      // print('imagePath: ${account!.imagePath}');
      account!.addressLine1 = _cAddressLine1.text.trim();
      account!.addressLine2 = _cAddressLine2.text.trim();
      account!.city = _cCity.text.trim();
      account!.state = _cState.text.trim();
      account!.country = _cCountry.text.trim();
      account!.namePrefix = _cNamePrefix.text.trim();
      account!.nameSuffix = _cNameSuffix.text.trim();
      account!.businessName = _cBusinessName.text.trim();
      account!.gstNo = _cGstNo.text.trim();
      if (_cPincode.text.isNotEmpty) {
        account!.pincode = int.parse(_cPincode.text.trim());
      }
      account!.isActive = _isActive!;
      account!.isDelete = false;
      print('${account!.accountType}');
      print('${account!.accountCode}');
      // print('${account!.accountType}');
      if (account!.id == null) {
        // add account
        _result = (await dbHelper.accountInsert(account!))!;
        account!.id = _result;
        //  hideLoader();
      } else {
        // update account
        _result = (await dbHelper.accountUpdate(account!))!;
        // hideLoader();
        AccountSearch accountSearch = AccountSearch();
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => AccountScreen(
                  redirectToCustomersTab: (isAddAsCustomer) ? true : false,
                  a: widget.analytics,
                  o: widget.observer,
                  accountSearch: accountSearch,
                )));
        // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CustomerTable()));
      }

      if (_result > 0) {
        // TimeOfDay tod = br.stringToTimeOfDay(_notificationTime);

        int notificationId = int.parse(
            global.moduleIds['Account'].toString() +
                '01' +
                account!.id.toString());
        if (account!.birthdate != null &&
            account!.anniversary != null &&
            account!.birthdate!.month == account!.anniversary!.month &&
            account!.birthdate!.day == account!.anniversary!.day &&
            (_oldBirthday != account!.birthdate ||
                _oldAnniversary != account!.anniversary)) {
          await br.scheduleNotification(
              notificationId,
              br
                  .getNextEventDate(account!.birthdate!)
                  .add(Duration(hours: tod.hour, minutes: tod.minute)),
              '${br.generateAccountName(account!)}\'s Birthday & Anniversary',
              'on ${DateFormat('MMMM dd').format(account!.birthdate!)}',
              '{"module":"Account","id":"${account!.id}"}',
              setNextDate: true);
        } else {
          if (account!.birthdate != null &&
              _oldBirthday != account!.birthdate) {
            int notificationId = int.parse(
                global.moduleIds['Account'].toString() +
                    '02' +
                    account!.id.toString());
            await br.scheduleNotification(
                notificationId,
                br
                    .getNextEventDate(account!.birthdate!)
                    .add(Duration(hours: tod.hour, minutes: tod.minute)),
                '${br.generateAccountName(account!)}\'s Birthday',
                'on ${DateFormat('MMMM dd').format(account!.birthdate!)}',
                '{"module":"Account","id":"${account!.id}"}',
                setNextDate: true);
          }
          if (account!.anniversary != null &&
              _oldAnniversary != account!.anniversary) {
            int notificationId = int.parse(
                global.moduleIds['Account'].toString() +
                    '03' +
                    account!.id.toString());
            await br.scheduleNotification(
                notificationId,
                br
                    .getNextEventDate(account!.anniversary!)
                    .add(Duration(hours: tod.hour, minutes: tod.minute)),
                '${br.generateAccountName(account!)}\'s Anniversary',
                'on ${DateFormat('MMMM dd').format(account!.anniversary!)}',
                '{"module":"Account","id":"${account!.id}"}',
                setNextDate: true);
          }
        }
        // hideLoader();
        setState(() {});
        if (returnScreenId == 0) {
          AccountSearch accountSearch = AccountSearch();
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => AccountScreen(
                    a: widget.analytics,
                    o: widget.observer,
                    accountSearch: accountSearch,
                    redirectToCustomersTab:
                        (isAddAsCustomer) ? true : false,
                  )));
          // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CustomerTable()));
        } else if (returnScreenId == 1) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop(account);
        }
        // else {
        //   // Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
        //   //     builder: (BuildContext context) =>  InvoiceAddSreen(
        //   //           analytics: analytics,
        //   //           observer: observer,
        //   //           routeName: routeName,
        //   //         )));
        // }
      }
    }
  } else {
    _autovalidate = true;
    setState(() {});
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Exception - accountAddScreen.dart - _onSubmit(): ' + e.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: Try to debug and find where the actual problem exists

Comment: You shouldn't just put `!` everywhere to get rid of the errors. Only do it when you are sure it can't be `null` at that point. In fact I would say it's good practice to try to avoid using `!` as much as possible. In any case, the error you get simply means that you use `!` somewhere on a variable that's null. Simply debug to find out where. My guess would be that `account` is null in that piece of code